# Latin characters only in HTML form

Tags: html, css, forms

I am looking to make it so that my HTML form will only accept characters from the Latin alphabet. The site is frequented by potential clients in the Middle East but they often type in Arabic or with characters from East Asian languages. I have tried to use code found elsewhere on the web but to no avail. I have pasted my form code below. How can I make this so? It is pasted within an iFrame on a Wix website.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<font face="helvetica" <META HTTPS-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
  <!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
  <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
  <form action="https://example.example.com/servlet/servlet.example?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" target='_parent'>

    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D0Y0000034cvq">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://example.com/successful-registration">

    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
    <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
    <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
    <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
    <!--  value="example.example@example.com">                                     -->
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

    <label for="first_name">First Name</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>


    <label for="middle_name">Middle Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="middle_name" maxlength="80" name="middle_name" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br> Date of Birth:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"> <input  id="00N0Y00000RWiNa" name="00N0Y00000RWiNa" size="12" type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder=" DD/MM/YYY" /></span><br><br>

    <label for="city">City</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

    <label for="country_code">Country</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="country_code" name="country_code"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SY">Syria</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <label for="mobile">Mobile</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br> Current/Previous School/University:&nbsp; &nbsp;<input id="00N0Y00000RWiNZ" maxlength="100"
      name="00N0Y00000RWiNZ" size="20" type="text" /><br><br> Course you would like to study: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="00N0Y00000RWiNi" maxlength="255" name="00N0Y00000RWiNi" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

    <label for="lead_source">Where did you hear about us?</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="lead_source" name="lead_source"><option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="School Counsellor_(Please specify)">School Counsellor_(Please specify)</option>
    <option value="University Website_(Please specify)">University Website_(Please specify)</option>
    <option value="Web">Web</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <input type=hidden id="00N0Y00000RWvPA" name="00N0Y00000RWvPA" type="checkbox" value="1" />

    <center><input type="submit" name="submit"></center>



  </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this code snippet. I have added the following change in the form element as an attribute.

```
accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"
```

ISO-8859-1 - Character encoding for the Latin alphabet.

Reference: 
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp

```html
<font face="helvetica" <META HTTPS-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
  <!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
  <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
  <form action="https://example.example.com/servlet/servlet.example?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" target='_parent' accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">

    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D0Y0000034cvq">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://example.com/successful-registration">

    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
    <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
    <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
    <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
    <!--  value="example.example@example.com">                                     -->
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

    <label for="first_name">First Name</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>


    <label for="middle_name">Middle Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="middle_name" maxlength="80" name="middle_name" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br> Date of Birth:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"> <input  id="00N0Y00000RWiNa" name="00N0Y00000RWiNa" size="12" type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder=" DD/MM/YYY" /></span><br><br>

    <label for="city">City</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

    <label for="country_code">Country</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="country_code" name="country_code"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SY">Syria</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <label for="mobile">Mobile</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br> Current/Previous School/University:&nbsp; &nbsp;<input id="00N0Y00000RWiNZ" maxlength="100"
      name="00N0Y00000RWiNZ" size="20" type="text" /><br><br> Course you would like to study: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="00N0Y00000RWiNi" maxlength="255" name="00N0Y00000RWiNi" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

    <label for="lead_source">Where did you hear about us?</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="lead_source" name="lead_source"><option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="School Counsellor_(Please specify)">School Counsellor_(Please specify)</option>
    <option value="University Website_(Please specify)">University Website_(Please specify)</option>
    <option value="Web">Web</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <input type=hidden id="00N0Y00000RWvPA" name="00N0Y00000RWvPA" type="checkbox" value="1" />

    <center><input type="submit" name="submit"></center>



  </form>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that! However, I noticed that this still allows people to type. It just displays in our CRM as a string of numbers instead of Arabic