# How to force number input to show english numbers no matter what system language is

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I  have a project that uses a lot of decimal numbers in input fields, some times users have an OS that is fully in Arabic, even numbers .. so when there is a big decimal number in an HTML input field, it is the not shown. Here is how the input fields HTML Looks like :

```
<input id="item_price" type="number" step="0.0001">
```

And here are images to show differences between English and Arabic numbers:

**English OS**
[image]

**Arabic OS**

[image]

As you see the decimal numbers are not showing when numbers are written in Arabic, any help about fixing this ??

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301332/latin-characters-only-in-html-form

Comment: Check [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) you can change number format like so `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat(format_type).format(number))`